# Draw connections between elements in logical circuits with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Could anyone help with making the logical circuit prettier. If you build the example, you'll see that the connections between elements look ugly.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
\draw (0,0) node[nand gate](NAND1){}
  ($(NAND1.north west)!.25!(NAND1.input 1)$) -- ++(-.5,0)
  (NAND1.input 1) -- ++(-.5,0)
  (NAND1.input 2) -- ++(-.5,0)
  ($(NAND1.south west)!.25!(NAND1.input 2)$) -- ++(-.5,0)
  (NAND1.output) -- ++(.5,0);
\draw  (0,2) node[nand gate](NAND2){}
  ($(NAND2.north west)!.25!(NAND2.input 1)$) -- ++(-.5,0)
  (NAND2.input 1) -- ++(-.5,0)
  (NAND2.input 2) -- ++(-.5,0)
  ($(NAND2.south west)!.25!(NAND2.input 2)$) -- ++(-.5,0)
  (NAND2.output) -- ++(.5,0);
\draw  (2,1) node[xnor gate](XNOR2){}
  (XNOR2.input 1)
  (XNOR2.input 2)
  (XNOR2.output) -- ++(.5,0);
\draw (NAND1.output) -| (XNOR2.input 1);
\draw (NAND2.output) -| (XNOR2.input 2); 
;\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Do you know you could use `node[nand gate, inputs=nnnn](NAND1){}` instead of manually adding two more inputs?

Answer (score 2):

You put NAND1 below NAND2, but input 1 is above input 2.  Also, you used ++ when + would do (not that it matters).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
\draw (0,0) node[nand gate](NAND1){}
  ($(NAND1.north west)!.25!(NAND1.input 1)$) -- +(-.5,0)
  (NAND1.input 1) -- +(-.5,0)
  (NAND1.input 2) -- +(-.5,0)
  ($(NAND1.south west)!.25!(NAND1.input 2)$) -- +(-.5,0);
\draw  (0,2) node[nand gate](NAND2){}
  ($(NAND2.north west)!.25!(NAND2.input 1)$) -- +(-.5,0)
  (NAND2.input 1) -- +(-.5,0)
  (NAND2.input 2) -- +(-.5,0)
  ($(NAND2.south west)!.25!(NAND2.input 2)$) -- +(-.5,0);
\draw  (2,1) node[xnor gate](XNOR2){}
  (NAND1.output) -- +(.5,0) |- (XNOR2.input 2)
  (NAND2.output) -- +(.5,0) |- (XNOR2.input 1)
  (XNOR2.output) -- +(.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-circ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(11.3,8)
\psset{invertoutput = true}
  \logicxor[ninputs = 2](6.8,3){}
  \logicand[ninputs = 4](0,0){}
  \logicand[ninputs = 4](0,6){}
  \psline(4.5,1)(5.4,1)(5.4,3.5)(6.8,3.5)
  \psline(6.8,4.5)(5.4,4.5)(5.4,7)(4.5,7)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Note**

`ninputs = <integer>` sets the number of inputs for each symbol. (The default is `ninputs = 2`.)

Comment: Kind of funny how every `tikz` question has a pstricks answer offered and every `pstricks` question has a `tikz` answer submitted.

Comment: `\logicand[ninputs=4](0,0){}`